# How to bind hex color to background angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a JSON file that stores hex color values in `option.colorChips.primary.hex` and I would like to create a button for each color, where the background of the button is the color in question. (note: `option.colorChips.primary.hex` only contains the 6 digit hex code, no # included)

Here is my template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let color of style.colors">
  <h1>{{ color.category }}</h1>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of color.options">
    <button [style.background]="option.colorChips.primary.hex">{{ option.name }} Color </button><br />
    {{ option.colorChips.primary.hex }} <br />
    </ng-container>
    <hr />
</ng-container>
```

You can see on line 4 my attempt. Why is this not working?

Comment: Does it work if you bind to a string with an hex code, e.g. `<button [style.background]="'#FF0000'">`? If yes, maybe you just need to prepend the `#` symbol to the hex code, i.e. `[style.background]="'#' + option.colorChips.primary.hex"`.

Comment: @AngularFrance, that worked! Step 2: how can I add a conditional (if `option.colorChips.primary.hex` is undefined - use default value (like white #FFFFFF). Thanks again!!

Comment: I've posted the solution as an answer. Please mark it as accepted if it fits the bill. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prepend the hex code with the `#` symbol, i.e.:

```html
<button [style.background]="'#'+option.colorChips.primary.hex"></button>
```

If you want to provide a default color, you can use the ternary operator:

```html
<button [style.background]="option.colorChips.primary.hex ? '#'+option.colorChips.primary.hex : '#FFFFFF'"></button>
```